# How can I dynamically switch the output destination of a script or command?

Tags: shell, files

I ran a shell command the other day which produced more output than expected.  It was writing to a file on a filesystem with very little available space and could have filled the filesystem.  The command took a long time to run so rather than rerunning it with a different output location, I would like to have been able to switch the output destination while it was running.  Is this possible?

I know that renaming the file wouldn't work because the system uses the inode number rather than the name, what options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one:

http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/

Comment: Please include some detail as to what the link contains; if the site goes down, the answer in its current state will be useless...